# Moment not converting the right date

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am converting a string into address, that's why i used moment :

My address : row[5] = "12/23/2015"

when i write : moment(row[5], 'MM/DD/RRRR').format('L');

Result : 12/23/2016

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: What is `RRRR`, it should be `YYYY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RRRR is an invalid format for momentjs. I suggest changing the format to what's below

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

If that works then we can deduce that your format was the issue.

So your code would be as below

```
moment(row[5], 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('L');
```

Comment: Thank you! it was the problem

Comment: still should wait 4 minutes :p